# Why does this isset return false?

Tags: php, forms, select, isset

So I have a select in a form...

```
<select id="aca" name="aca">
  <option value="2012">2012-2013</option>
  <option value="2011">2011-2012</option>
  <option value="2010">2010-2011</option>
  <option value="2009">2009-2010</option>
  <option value="2008">2008-2009</option>
  <option value="2007">2007-2008</option>
  <option value="2006">2006-2007</option>
  <option value="2005">2005-2006</option>
</select>
```

Looks good, right ? Then I want to check if the whole form is set:

```
if(isset($_FILES['fichier']) && isset($_POST['nom']) && isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['c']) && isset($_POST['t']) && isset($_POST['auteur']) && isset($_POST['aca'])) echo 'tout';
```

Well this always return FALSE, and I know it's due to 'aca'. When I try...

```
if(isset($_POST['aca'])) echo 'aca';
```

It returns TRUE **if** I selected something in the list, and the other condition still doesn't echo 'tout', so I just see 'aca'. And this js line doesn't seem to be the problem as other select's return TRUE.

```
$("select").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

I really don't understand... HALP ^^"

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Upload</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/upload.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/upload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>Informations d'upload</legend>
<p>Fichier (tous formats | max. 1 Mo):</p>
<input type="file" name="fichier" size="60"/><br/>
<p>Nom du fichier. Caractères utilisables: alphanumériques °*@()-_()</p>
<input type="text" name="nom" size="40"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Classification</legend>
<p>Merci d'indiquer où ce fichier devra être classé.</p>
  <select id="a" name="a">
    <option value="0">BA1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="c" name="c" style="display:none"></select>
  <select id="t" name="t" style="display:none"></select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Détails</legend>
<p>Auteur:</p>
<input type="text" name="auteur" size="40"/>
<p>Année académique:</p>
<select id="aca" name="aca">
  <option value="2012">2012-2013</option>
  <option value="2011">2011-2012</option>
  <option value="2010">2010-2011</option>
  <option value="2009">2009-2010</option>
  <option value="2008">2008-2009</option>
  <option value="2007">2007-2008</option>
  <option value="2006">2006-2007</option>
  <option value="2005">2005-2006</option>
</select>
</fieldset>

<br/>

<div style="width:500px;text-align:center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Full PHP:

```
<?php
$formats = array('pdf');
echo strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['fichier']['name'],'.'),1)).'<br/>';
if(isset($_POST['aca'])) echo 'aca';
if(isset($_FILES['fichier']) && isset($_POST['nom']) && isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['c']) && isset($_POST['t']) && isset($_POST['auteur']) && isset($_POST['aca'])) echo 'tout';
if(preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9éè°*@ ()_-]{10,50}$#",$_POST['nom']))
{
echo 'OK';
}
else echo 'Nope';
?>
```

Comment: We need more information to go on. The HTML and the relevant PHP code would be helpful.

Comment: uhhh... how do you know all of those other things are set? Obviously `aca` is set, so it must be one of the others. Print them all and see which one is not set.

Comment: When I remove `isset($_POST['aca'])` from the condition it returns TRUE as expected.

Comment: your select element must have a value attribute or the post will receive nothing but the name with not value and enctype="multipart/form-data" is not needed unless you are sending a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing is selected, the element doesn't POST to the server.  You can fix this by making the select:

```
<select id="aca" name="aca">
  <option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
  <option value="2012">2012-2013</option>
  <option value="2011">2011-2012</option>
  <option value="2010">2010-2011</option>
  <option value="2009">2009-2010</option>
  <option value="2008">2008-2009</option>
  <option value="2007">2007-2008</option>
  <option value="2006">2006-2007</option>
  <option value="2005">2005-2006</option>
</select>
```

And again, you must do this for the other "select" elements if you want them to POST without selecting something.

Comment: The other select elements returned TRUE for a while even though nothing was selected. Now they don't. Some mysterious things happen U_ù But well you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Do a print_r($_POST) and you will be able to see exactly what is set...